# Testing program java

Tags: java, testing

I have written a program, and now I am required to write a "runnable test script" to test it.

I suppose a runnable test script means a main method.

But all the methods call of the program are trigger when mouse clicked a button, or input from `OptionPane`.
So, How can I write a runnable test script to control mouse click?

I don't know if I have describe the problem clearly. The program is a project task management tool, so you can clicked button to create a new project, save project, add tasks, add staff members, and so on. The problem is how do I control which button is to click by java code?

Here is a method that is called when a button is clicked:

```
public void newProject() {
    if (currentProject == null || showConfirm(
            "The current progress will not be saved.\nContinue?")) {

        resetCurrentProject();
        //Get the name of the new project
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, 
                "Please give a name to the project", "New Project", 
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (name != null) {

          //Initialize the a new project
            ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
            ArrayList<Staff> staffList = new ArrayList<Staff>();

            //Create a new Project instance
            try {
                currentProject = new Project(name, staffList, taskList);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                showError(e1.getMessage());
            }

            //Update the project information panel        
            updateProjectInfoPane();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't control the mouse, you get a reference to the button, and fire some "click"-event by code.

Comment: How to fire click event?

Comment: what about the input of the JOptionPane?

Comment: First of all, are you using Swing to create the GUI?

Comment: I have solved the problem by Abbot Java GUI Testing

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation: Instead of actually controlling the mouse, you get a reference to the button you want to emulate a click on. After you have a reference to the JButton (assuming Swing), you can call `doClick()` on it (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29).

For JOptionPane I have no idea, since I've never used it and don't know what it does, but the documentation can be found here regardless: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing this, I would separate the interface from the logic. This way, my buttons are just calling underlying classes, my displays are calling underlying classes, and I can make my test script just call the underlying classes too!

Consider the following as if it wasn't swing but some other type of interface. The example I gave is pretty lame, because all it does is increment. But the idea is that any logic Incrementer has is now encapsulated in the class. This means it can be easily tested, extended, and modified if necessary.

```
// bad
class GUI {
    Button b = new ...
    int i = 0;
    TextArea t = new ...

    // bad code
    actionPerformed(Button b) {
        if(b == this.b) i++; // on button press increment
    }
    // whatever, you get the idea
    paint(Graphics g) {
        t.setText(i + "");
    }

}

// good code
class GUI {
    Button b = new ...
    int i = 0;
    TextArea t = new ...

    // bad code
    actionPerformed(Button b) {
        if(b == this.b) i.increment(); // on button press increment
    }
    // whatever, you get the idea
    paint(Graphics g) {
        t.setText(i.toString());
    }

}

class Incrementer {
    int value;
    void increment() { value++; }
    public String toString() { return Integer.valueOf(value); }
}
```

Comment: I know, and it's good in principle and all, but it's "if you were writing it", not "if you had already written it".

Comment: @Alxandr I do this every day at for my 9-5. I did this for my assignments when I was in university. It's also the only way to do it (barring Selenium or java.awt.Robot) for a project like this.

Comment: @glowcoder: I did separate interface from logic, but the calling methods involve a lot of other private helper method which does all the checking

Comment: @XiaofanWu It's a pretty standard practice to not test private methods. There's no value in testing something users never see. I know this isn't intuitive on the surface, but it's fairly common to operate this way. I'm not saying everyone skips private methods, but it's very common to do so. Essentially you'd need to break encapsulation in order to add them to a unit test. This would put the object in a state the user wouldn't be using it in, making the test less worthwhile.

Comment: @Alxandr There's a huge difference between the two. Let us presume that the logic of incrementing was used all over our application. In like 40 places. And not just this application, but a dozen other applications too. Now all of a sudden, the geniuses in marketing advertise "Our increments are twice as big as our competitors!" and just expect development to follow through on it. Well crap... Now you have to change the incrementing logic in 40 places! In the second example, you change it once, it gets tested by the `IncrementTest`, and you happily ship to production.

Comment: -.-. Have you read your own code? I can find **no** difference between your "good" and your "bad" code, since you probably just copy-pasted them and forgot to change one of them.

Comment: @Alxandr Well, let's see. One uses a primitive operator (`i++`) and the other uses an `Incrementor` object. Yes it's a trivial example, but it's one that can be (and, according to OP, it was) extended to other, less trivial behaviors.

Comment: @Alxandr I will admit I didn't change the `//bad code` comment in the `actionPerformed` snippet when I should've. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Clicking buttons (i.e. GUI) is not the sort of thing you should test (extensively). Leave it to the testers - they either test it manually or automate (Selenium, QTP).

I'm guessing you're required to write some unit tests...? In this case just write a test for each of your methods and job done. You're not supposed to test the front-end, but just the logic. For example, test your  newProject() method by writing a unit test that checks whether the new project was initialised correctly. So, from your test method you call newProject() and assert if a new instance of the Project was created or not.

Some decent tutorial: http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/unit-testing-with-junit-and-easymock.html

GUI testing - do simple checks yourself (manual clicking) and pass it on to testers. If you don't work with any testers then I'm afraid the way to go is: 1. keep testing manually after any significant change, 2. Consider using Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/ or any other automation tool.

HTH,
Damo